# java Web Start is running slower than normal application running

Tags: java-web-start

I'm having trouble with Web Start.

There is no problem if I start the application from IntelliJ.

With Web Start it's working ok most of the time but at a point I'm loading 10000 records from database and there it's getting very slow.

What can I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that running as a WebStart application, your application has diferent memory settings. You should attempt to tweak those (as described [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)) and see if that makes a difference with application performance.

Other than that, you should profile your application to see where the delays occur (which parts of the application, what kind of operations, constantly or intermittently etc.)

Comment: as far as I see the problem is with UI,
I will try your suggesstions thank you

Comment: I profiled the problem was one of the apis using assertions too much, so disabling the assertions with WebStart solved it,

Thanks,